# multiple queue: consumers: start async.operations.all in parallel

Tags: rabbit-mq, async

I would like to know why asynchronous operations processes queue: consumers: start async.operations.all are started every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using an external consumer for the `async.operations.all` task the Magento cron job makes sure the consumers processes are running.

Comment: The problem is that I have the cron executing every 10 minutes and I observe that every time the cron is executed a new async.operations.all thread appears and this causes deadlock to appear when using the bulk api